# User Warning Form Keras 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-2

I'm trying to reproduce [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-keras-d804b2e04ef8) work but I receive the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(outputs=Tensor("de..., inputs=Tensor("in...)`
```

when I run line 84:

```
model_final = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)
```

I have the following packages installed:

- ipython==6.2.1
- Keras==2.0.8
- tensorflow==1.3.0
- tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.5

It seems the code is written in an older version of Keras although still works under my version of Keras.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API:
`Model(inputs=[<tf.Tenso…, outputs=Tensor(“ma…)`
model = Model(input=[sentence_input, neg_input], output=loss)
```

Here we can see that the new api of keras, the `input` and `output` should be `inputs` and `outputs`.

The original code is:

```
model = Model(input=[sentence_input, neg_input], output=loss)
```

So if we want to get this warning away, we should write like this:

```
model = Model(inputs=[sentence_input, neg_input], outputs=loss)
```

> Just a little s here and there, that’s all.